# Use count of each Series intance as Y values

Tags: c#, winforms, charts

This is the code I have so far, basically it's getting the actual value of uniqueid and using that as the value for each series:

```
string[] XPointMember = new string[table.Rows.Count];
int[] YPointMember = new int[table.Rows.Count];

for (int count = 0; count < table.Rows.Count; count++)
{                 
    XPointMember[count] = table.Rows[count]["GuitarBrand"].ToString();

    YPointMember[count] = Convert.ToInt32(table.Rows[count]["UniqueID"]);
}
//binding chart control  
chart1.Series[0].Points.DataBindXY(XPointMember, YPointMember);
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is adding the count of each instance of that guitar brand to show as the value. So if there are 4 instances of a particular GuitarBrand than the value should be 4.

Thanks!

Comment: So the X axis should be GuitarBrand and the Y axis should be the number of rows that have that particular GuitarBrand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
//First populate the X axis only (the series)
for (int index = 0; index < table.Rows.Count; index++)
{
    XPointMember[index] = table.Rows[index]["GuitarBrand"].ToString();
}

//Loop again, and for each series, use the Count method
//to see how much occurrences of the same guitar brand are there
for (int index = 0; index < table.Rows.Count; index++)
{
    var guitar_brand = XPointMember[index];

    YPointMember[index] = XPointMember.Count(x => x == guitar_brand);
}
```

Please note that I used `index` instead of `count` for the loop variable. Using `count` here makes it confusing for the reader of the code.